# Is it possible to send a private message via Facebook GRAPH API?

Tags: facebook

I really need a solution. Facebook messages seem to be "read-only".
I use javascript.

f.e. {conversation-id}/messages?message={"hello there"}
(not working)

Answer (score 0):

You can use their [chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) until April 2015. After that, [its gone](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't send private message via Facebook GRAPH API, you can't do that via FQL too, but there is a solution:
There is a way to send message to user's primary inbox, you need a library which is completely open source (by me) then:

```
<?php
require_once('send.message.php'); //requires file
require_once('facebook.php'); //sdk provided by facebook, you need one for tokens and
//all
$config = array('appId' => '1496661733888719' ,'secret'=>'0c959ab2dec71c5a53aab1cd64751223' );
$facebook=new Facebook($config);
if(!$facebook->getUser()){
    $params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_mailbox, xmpp_login',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/'
    );
    $url=$facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    header("location:".$url);
    die();
}
$messageobj=new SendMessage($facebook);

$receiverId=''; // this may either be username or userID, this class takes care of both the //cases
$body='test message';
if($messageobj->sendMessage($body,$receiverId))
{
echo 'message sent';
}else
{
echo 'some error occured';
}
?>
```

In this way you can send message to users, you can get the detailed information on this at:

[nishgtm.com/2013/11/facebook-message-api-php/](http://nishgtm.com/2013/11/facebook-message-api-php/)

You will also find the link to github page on the above link. This library is super easy to use. Feel free to ask me anything via comments.